# HTML <input> with selective editing of date (persistent placeholder text)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime, input

I'm looking for a way of making an input field for entering a date and time with persistent placeholder text. It should:

- support displaying continuously a placeholder text with a format, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`
- allow to edit only digits of the format (placeholder text)
- skip to a next group of digits (day, month, year) after filling a current one

Something like Chrome's default controls for `<input type="datetime-local">` would be great but it needs to work for Firefox and Internet Explorer 11.

I started implementing a solution where I have two `input` fields - one behind another. The one behind would be styles as a placeholder and updated on text modifications of another one (in front).

And I cannot believe there's nothing simulating this behavior anywhere...

I want to use it in AngularJS but any kind of script should be easy to adapt. This is going to handle just one fixed datetime format so it could be very simplified solution.

Answer (score 0):

Through some plain Javascript, I did what you suggested. It's different from your solution though. It doesn't function exactly like type=datetime-local, but with some more time and effort, it can be done. I hope this helps you:

```js
year.onkeydown = validateInput;
year.onkeyup = tab;
month.onkeydown = validateInput;
month.onkeyup = tab;
day.onkeydown = validateInput;
day.onkeyup = tab;

function validateInput() {
  /*Unicode stuff*/
  var character = [8, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 190];
  var unicode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
  /*Filters Invalid Characters Like Letters*/
  if (character.indexOf(unicode) === -1) {
    return false;
  }
  /*Allow backspacing*/
  else if (character.indexOf(unicode) === 0) {
    return true;
  } 
  /*Only allow up to four characters in year*/
  else if (this.value.length >= 4 && this.id === 'year') {
    return false;
  }
  /*only allow up to two characters in month and date*/
  else if (this.value.length >= 2 && (this.id === 'day' || this.id === 'month')) {
    return false;
  }
}

/*This funciton puts the focus of the element to the next element, hence automatic tbbing*/
function tab() {
  if (this.value.length >= 4 && this.id === 'year') {
    this.nextElementSibling.focus();
  } else if (this.value.length >= 2 && (this.id === 'day' || this.id === 'month')) {
    this.nextElementSibling.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
#year, #month, #day {
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='year' placeholder='yyyy'>
<input type='text' id='month' placeholder='mm'>
<input type='text' id='day' placeholder='dd'>
```

Good luck!